# Open a file with notepad and save it, using vbscript

Tags: windows, vbscript, process, scripting, notepad

My problem is that I want to open a file in notepad and then save it from notepad, not manually but using vbscript (the reason I want this is to overcome some encoding issues). Until now I have found a relevant [article](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-objects/specific-tasks/openfile-savefile-dialogs.html) which should solve my problem, but it doesn't work. It has this code:

```
Dim notepad, wndNotepad, strDesktop

Set notepad = Sys.Process("notepad")
Set wndNotepad = notepad.Window("Notepad")

' Open a file in Notepad
wndNotepad.MainMenu.Click("File|Open...")
notepad.Window("#32770", "Open").OpenFile "C:\Program Files\SmartBear\TestComplete 12\install.txt"

' Save the file to the desktop
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
wndNotepad.MainMenu.Click "File|Save as..."
notepad.Window("#32770", "Save As").SaveFile strDesktop & "\install.txt"
```

The problem is that vbscript can't recognize the Sys in the second line (`Sys.Process`). I assume that in this line a process for notepad should be created ([like here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx)) and then something like an object of this process to be returned to the variable notepad (something I don't know if and how can be achived) in order to be used in the third line (`notepad.Window("Notepad")`).

If anyone has any idea how the code should be in order to work, I would really appreciate the help. Also any other suggestions on how to solve this problem (or any ideas about if it can actually be solved) are very welcome. Thank you for your time.

**EDIT**

As I said in the comments below, the above code needs the TestComplete software which is expensive. So if anyone has any idea for resolving my issue in another way (other software, other code, other programming language) I would be glad to learn it.

Comment: I would use a text stream. Set the `Charset` property to what your file is, read the file, change the `charset`, and write it back. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The short answer is Sys.Process isn't In any of the Windows native libraries, it requires additional libraries. Might want to search google to find out which library(dll) has those processes and functions.

Comment: The code you posted isn't valid VBScript. Besides, why would you want to open a text file in notepad only to save it under a different name in the first place? Just copy the file. For resolving encoding issues: post a question describing the actual issues.

Comment: Thank you all for your time. I found that in order to use this code you need to have TestComplete software installed (the dll that @Steve Clines suggested), which is really expensive, so I have to find another way to solve my problem. If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If it's just encoding, provide a sample of the file. What you're seeing, what you want to see and we can help you rebuild it with native libraries efficiently.

Comment: A hexdump of the first couple bytes of the file would probably be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to copy a file from one path to another. Please refer the below code for copying Files,

Function CopyFile()

```
strSourceFile = "c:\.....\source.txt"
strDestFile = "c:\.....\dest.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Check to see if the file is read-only
If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes And 1 Then 
    'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
    fso.CopyFile strSourceFile, strDestFile, strOverWrite
Else 
    'The file exists and is read-only.
    'Remove the read-only attribute
    fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes - 1
    'Replace the file
    fso.CopyFile strSourceFile, strDestFile, strOverWrite
    'Reapply the read-only attribute
    fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes + 1
End If
```

End Function

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wanted the code to open notepad and then save it with notepad. The reason was a difference I saw in encodings of the two files (the original and the file after saving with notepad). Finally, I found out that this was not necessary and would not solve my problem with the encodings.